# Where do I declare my collections in MeteorJS?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to mongodb and MeteorJs, in the tutorials I have seen there has been a single Main.js file where collections are declared at the top. However, with (what must be recent) updates there is now a server/main.js and a client/main.js file, since my collection needs to be accessible for both where/which file should I create it?

Answer (score 1):

be sure to read the guide on application structure: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

per the guide, i make domain areas within /imports and put my collections there. e.g. if i have a collection for parties, it would most likely go here:

```
/imports/api/parties/Parties.js
```

... and to publish it:

```
/imports/api/parties/server/partiesPublish.js
```

also: files in /imports are not eagerly grabbed, so in any place you need the collection, you would have to import it. follow the guide for import/export syntax: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export

Answer (score 0):

Put your collections in any folder except `client/` or `server/`

like `startup/collections.js` or `/imports/api/module/collections.js`

If you put your collections in `client/` folder they will be available only on the client. The same is true for `server/`.

I case you do use import don't forget:

```
export const Sources = new Mongo.Collection( "Sources" );
```

and use them when you needed

```
import { Sources } from '/imports/startup/collections.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not create a to complicated folder structure for now.

Let say you keep your default `Meteor create` folder structure

Which should have :

```
-Client
-Server

// Add a Common, Public & Private folder at the root level
-common ( declare your and export your collections as default )
-public ( Images & assets folder accesible from the root domain ) 
-private ( private stuff )
```

Anything, not in *Server* or *Client* will run on **both** sides.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per Meteor 1.4.4.2 guideline, just have a look at below package structure(it is partially shown here, actually it includes lot many things)

```
PROJECT_NAME_HERE

    |____imports

              |_____api

                    |_____[YOUR_MODULE_NAME]

                            |_____ server
                                    |_______publication.js
                                    -link.js
```

> **Note: Any folder named server shall run on the server side**

**link.js** contains the initialization of collection as below

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Links = new Mongo.Collection('links');
```

**publication.js** by name itself, has the code to publish the collection in Meteor from server side

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Links } from '../links.js';

Meteor.publish('links.all', function () {
  return Links.find();
});
```

This shall not work until you register above publication at the server side, so you must declare the registration in file **imports\startup\server\register-api.js** as below,

```
import '../../api/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/server/publications.js';
```

The above collection example can be developed by just creating a full meteor project using below command;

```
meteor create --full PROJECT_NAME_HERE
```

Above generated code has all the code developed for you, you just need to analyze the bits.